# how to connect Worklight 6.1 to DB2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, db2-connect

I am developing a hybrid application which needs database connectivity to store and retrieve data.I am using IBM db2 database and worklight 6.1. I need the javascript code to connect to db2 so that I can enter information directly to the database from the apps UI and data from db2 should be displayed on the screen.(i.e.both side connectivity-->data retieval and storage in the database)

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to DB2.

What you *really* need to do is [to read the SQL adapter training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development), and learn how to send data to and retrieve data from - a database. Then you need to review the sample project provided in the same URL above.

You can also take a look at the following (after you read the training module). The concept is the same in nature, just for DB2...:

- http://wpcertification.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/connecting-to-database-from-worklight.html

Comment: Thanks a lot..The above code helped me a lot..I cannot pass the parameters through my javascript function while calling the adapter procedure to execute the query...please also guide me with adapter procedure while accepting the parameters and implementing the query